# remove spaces between columns exported to textfile

Tags: c#

I am using c# windows application to get data from database and display on datagridview and exporting to text file
I want to remove empty spaces between  below 4 columns .

```
2  
vehicle control services ltd 
Brom
Malkit
```

i get `2 vehicle control services ltd brom mal`, but i want it to be like `2vehicle control services ltdBromMlkit`

this is my code.

```
string stringSql = " SELECT distinct  " +
                "'" + comboBox6.Text + "' as RecordType" +
               " , left([Claimant Name] +'                              ',30) " +
                " , left([Claimant Address1] +'                             ',30)  " +
                " , left([Claimant Address2] +'                             ',30) as ClaimantAddress2 " +
                " , left([Claimant Address3] +'                             ',30) as
```

exporting to text file code

```
 if (obj == null || obj == Convert.DBNull)
                return "";

            // if string has no ','
            if (obj.ToString().IndexOf(",") == -1)
                return obj.ToString();

            // remove backslahes
            return "\"" + obj.ToString() + "\"";
        }

        private void ExportDatatviewToCsv(string iFilename, DataView dv)
        {
            // Open output stream
            StreamWriter swFile = new StreamWriter(iFilename);


            // Rows of Data
            foreach (DataRowView rowData in dv)
            {
                string[] colData = new string[dv.Table.Columns.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < dv.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    object obj = rowData[i];
                    colData[i] = GetWriteableValueForCsv(obj);
                }

                // Write data in row
                swFile.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", colData));
            }

            // Close output stream
            swFile.Close();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (myDataset == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (myDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            DataView vwExport = new DataView(myDataset.Tables[0]);
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "TXT file|*.txt";
            sfd.FileName = "ee "  + ".txt";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                if (sfd.FileName != "")
                {
                    ExportDatatviewToCsv(sfd.FileName, vwExport);
                    MessageBox.Show("File has been saved as: " + Environment.NewLine + sfd.FileName + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "NB: This dataset has been ordered by t_reference in ascending order. If being combined with an existing dataset - that dataset will also need to be sorted in this way.", "Operation complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }


  }
```

Comment: That code isn't the cause, your SQL part is working correctly. What code are you using to export from the datagridview to the text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make it clear what I think you are asking...

You currently get this for each line:

> 2 vehicle control services ltd brom mal

but you want it like this for each line (which let me point out makes absolutely no sense at all, it doesn't look very usable):

> 2vehicle control services ltdBromMlkit

If that is the case then in your code just replace this line:

```
swFile.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", colData));
```

with this line:

```
swFile.WriteLine(string.Join("", colData));
```

Notice that it will now join the string with an empty string, rather than joining with the single space that you don't want.